# Java passing/displaying a Int value to a new activity on click

Tags: java, android

I have a button with a set variable, I want to pass that value across to a new activity once clicked. It doesn't know that "score" is a int in my second activity. I cant seem to display it. Any ideas?

main activity

```
public Button but2;
int score = 10;
public void borrow() {
    but2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent car = new Intent (MainActivity.this,borrow.class);
            car.putExtra("score", score);
            startActivity(car);
        }
    });
}
```

second activity

```
public class borrow extends AppCompatActivity {


Intent car = getIntent();
int score = car.getIntExtra("score", 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do like this in the second activity, inside onCreate method not outside

```
public class borrow extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int score = intent.getIntExtra("score", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: any idea why this doesnt output the score?
 `System.out.println(score);`